# Is it possible send a gif image correctly without breaking it?

Tags: mosaico, images, jquery

I'm trying to create a email mosaico template with image .gif but jquery resize my image and send gif broken. Is there any option to send a .gif correctly?

Thank you.

Comment: I've reproduced this - create a new email using versafix-1 template. Select the 258x150 image block. Upload a gif. Preview - it's not working! :(

Comment: I was also able to replicate this using the mosaico.io template builder https://mosaico.io/ - this suggests this is a mosaico issue not a civicrm issue per say

Comment: As a temporary workaround try manually uploading the gif then link to it using an <img> tag.

Answer (score 2):

Did you find an answer to your question? It seems that the platform does not accept the .gif format.

---

Admin support and I figured it out... kinda:

1. It works if you use the "traditional" email. The Mosaico version
   seems to strip the gifs away.
2. If I view the resulting email through
   our standard email reader, it moves. If I view it through outlook,
   it does not.

Conclusion - Even if you get the gif to upload and go
    out properly, it doesn't work on all email readers and therefore is
    not a good solution for your email.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with the `intervention` library used, which doesn't support animated GIFs.  The [intervention bug](https://github.com/Intervention/image/issues/176) is 5+ years old.

While intervention is open source, the maintainer is mostly inactive, and hasn't released the source code of his new version, which he's been working on for years.  I think it might be time to remove intervention from Mosaico.

Note also that there's an [open Mosaico issue](https://github.com/veda-consulting/uk.co.vedaconsulting.mosaico/issues/285) for this topic.

Answer (score 2):

I tried to do this - 2.8 v of Mosaico extension and Deprecate iMagick PHP extension - didn't work. In the end I made the animated GIF from a movie I put into Keynote (Mac) and then exported as an animated gif. I then resized it on ezgif.com to size 534px wide, which is a preset size for Mosaico images. I then uploaded the image to a server and hard-coded the image URL into a Mosaico text field. All worked fine.